# Can't install packages due to "ImportError: No module named six"

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip

I seem to have messed up my python install. I can't install new python packages:

```
$ pip install arq
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/Users/me/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    import six
ImportError: No module named six
```

And trying to address this error directly gives the same error:

```
$ pip install six
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/Users/me/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    import six
ImportError: No module named six
```

I'm not really sure what to do. All pip operations seem to fail for the same reason. `pip freeze` and just `pip` give the same result.

I'm on osx.

Comment: Have you tried un-installing and reinstalling `six`? As stupidly simple as that sounds, I might work. Also, try doing `sudo apt-get install python-pip` if your running on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

This is inspired by @Christian Dean's comment. But I am on OSX so what I did was to just reinstall pip from here:

http://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing/